# How to remove background in an image with a human in android java

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I am trying to develop a simple app where it will identify and remove the background of a human in image. I am researching but unable to get a point of start to understand how to identify any complex background and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into OpenCV, it's an open source computer vision library. If you want to remove a background from a person that's a relative hard task for a beginner. I'd suggest watching some tutorials or reading them on various websites such as:
https://docs.opencv.org/
https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/
etc.